# Run a shell script on button press with swift

Tags: swift, macos-sierra

I want to make a menu bar app which hides the desktop. I have the terminal command: `defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool FALSE;killall Finder`

But I'm not sure how to insert this into my swift code so it runs when a button is pressed. Any tips would be great!

**Edit:** Running Xcode 8.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try NSTask.

Here is a sample Hello world code snippet

```
    let path = "/usr/bin/say"
    let arguments = ["hello world"]
    let task = NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath(path, arguments: arguments)
    task.waitUntilExit()
```

You can find some references [here](http://scriptingosx.com/2016/05/build-an-application-to-run-a-shell-command-in-xcode-and-swift-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

In swift, NSTask has been renamed to "process" now. You may try something like this:

```
    let path = "/usr/bin/say"
    let arguments = ["Hello World"]
            
    let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
    task.waitUntilExit()
```